# eigen sparseMatrix get nonzero elements of a specific column/row

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

i want to use Eigen::sparseMatrix with double values and be able to retrieve all non zero elements of a specific column or row. Is it possible to do that without iterate over all elements ?
kind regards

Matt

Comment: Did you check the "Iterating over the nonzero coefficients" section of [this page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title2)? This only works efficiently if you iterate along the inner dimension. If not, you can consider transposing the matrix or you need to re-think your algorithm.

Comment: thank you for the link, yes i have seen that. probably my need cannot be fulfilled with the eigen sparse matrix for both row and col.
for the moment i created a class containing 2 std::map<int, std::map<int, double>> (for col and row access).

Comment: I doubt that having 2 `std::map<std::map<>>` is more efficient than storing two `Eigen::SparseMatrix` -- but that is hard to say without more context.

Comment: maps of maps isn't a great choice since you would still need to iterate over all rows to find the elements belonging to a single column or vice-versa. Maybe boost's multi index could help you here. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html However, this would still be pretty slow. Depending on your exact use case, we may be able to come up with a better solution.

Comment: You may actually be better off keeping two copies of the matrix. One row-major and one column-major. Maybe with a simple wrapper that invalidates one copy when the other is changed and re-creates the copy when it is accessed. I think you would actually save a lot of memory with this compared to using maps, which have a notoriously high overhead.

Comment: @Homer512 two sparse matrix (row major and col major) seems to be a good idea. I think I will implement that. I didn't know the boost multi index, thank you for these tips